# Get some sort of identifier of device with iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, identifier

I need a way to tie a device to a username/password through an iOS app.  Nowever it seems there isnt any good options out there.  The reason for doing this is I want this app to access private information only once so it cant be shared between devices.  I really want the Apple ID of the user so it can work on say an Iphone and Ipad of theirs but still be shared only by their account.  Any other suggestions on how to accomplish this task from an app?

Comment: Use advertising identifier

Comment: http://techcrunch.com/2014/02/03/apples-latest-crackdown-apps-pulling-the-advertising-identifier-but-not-showing-ads-are-being-rejected-from-app-store/

Comment: But I am using google , flurry  , MAT Which are not showing advertisment but still they are asking for it ...

Comment: @KrunalDarji next time you submit an update if you flag IDFA usage but don't display ads you will get rejected.  Apple is not proactively removing apps that violate this policy if they were approved before it came into effect

Answer (score 1):

The only identifier you have available is `identifierForVendor` - This identifier will be unique to the device (and your application) as long as your application is installed.  If the application is deleted and re-installed it may change.

Even if you could get a unique device identifier you will still need to provide the ability for the user to change their device (e.g. when they buy a new one) so `identifierForVendor` should be functionally equivalent.

Comment: Nice that might work.